# ActionSheet within UISplitViewController acts different in Portrait Mode than Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uiactionsheet

I created a new application using the Split View-based Application template.

I then added an Action Button to the rootViewController navigation controller called actionButton.

When the button is pressed, I display an ActionSheet like this:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil
    otherButtonTitles:@"Admin Functions", @"Refresh Data", nil];
[actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:actionButton animated:YES];
[actionSheet release];
```

After I press the button when in landscape mode it displays the action sheet in a popover which is pointing to  the button (as I expected it to):

[image: Landscape Mode]

However, in Portrait mode it looks completely different and the menu comes up from the bottom of the rootViewController popover just like it does on the iPhone:

[image: Portrait Mode]

My question is, how do I make the ActionSheet appear at the top while in portrait mode, just like it does when in landscape mode?

Since this is a "utility menu", it isn't really tied directly to the data being displayed so it shouldn't be part of the popover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is by design, if it were a popover in portrait mode you would then have 2 levels of popover.

This is technically possible by implementing your own version of UIPopover or using one someone has already written ([WEPopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)).

However, this is a poor design choice. You say that the functions aren't related to the data, however one is 'refresh data'. I would replace the action button with a refresh icon such as the one Apple uses in 'Find my Friends':

[image: Refresh Button]

The other, 'Admin Functions', if not directly related to the data in the list, perhaps needs a new home, maybe with the main view of your app? It's hard to say where is best to put it without knowing more about the structure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, the pictures that I showed were only mockups and meant to simply show what it is doing and the specific actions are different.  The actual app is very similar to the Mail app with the left view showing a list while the right view shows details.  Since the menu items refer to the application as a whole (and not the detail item) I feel that it belongs in the left view.  This page IS the main view of my app, so I need to find a place to put the menu items.  With 5-6 items on the menu, it really needs to be a drop down menu because of the limited room.

Comment: The problem still remains that you have two levels of UIPopover (the list and then the menu). If you were willing to eschew the list being in a popover in portrait mode and just existing on the left, I'd recommend using [MSSplitViewController](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/) instead of using UISplitViewController. It's hard to a devise a better course of action without knowing more app specifics, however.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you could move the action button from right edge of the root view controller's bar to the left edge of the detail view controller's bar.

For example, if the action button were located just to the right of the vertical bar in your first screen shot (meaning it's at the left edge of the detail view controller's bar), then when you rotate to portrait mode it would appear just to the right of the Events button in your second screen shot.  You could still call UIActionSheet's `showFromBarButtonItem:animated` method, which would display your action sheet in popup mode.

There's still the question of whether you really want two popovers on the screen at the same time.  But if you do, this is how to do it.

Comment: From the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS: "Note: You should always dismiss the visible popover before displaying another view controller modally. For specific guidelines on when and how to use popovers in your application, see “Popover (iPad Only)” in iOS Human Interface Guidelines."